# Windows 7 builtin Backup and Restore - cannot turn off

Tags: windows-7, backup

Windows 7 Home Premium, service pack 1. I recently turned on the built in Backup and Restore facility, pointing it at an external USB drive (500GB) I'd bought for the purpose. Now, I can't unmount the USB drive, the computer is much slower, noisier, and swaps out more. I can't delete the files from the USB drive, and the Backup control panel says there is no backup there, but the files are there and consuming half the drive.

And, ***I  can't  turn  off  the  Backup  service***!

Is it possible to turn off Windows 7 built in backup service once you've given it a drive? I know how to stop a particular backup run, I want to completely permanently turn off the Backup and Restore service.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows system events if there any possible error messages showing reason for these issue. You can access the Windows system events from "eventvwr.msc" command.

Also check whether the logged in user has enough privilege to access the external USB drive. You can check this by creating, editing and deleting a text file in the external USB drive.

Comment: USB drive permissions: Done, do have permissions.

Comment: Windows system events log - I've just looked at this, many days after the events. Possibly useful information there, but I can't find it in the verbosity. Thanks for the tip, though.